# Convert array of strings to one integer

Tags: javascript, arrays

do you know how to convert an array of strings to one integer?

Example:

```
var array = ["1","2","3","4"];
```

to

```
var number = 1234;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go, just need to join the array and parse the integer out:

```js
var array = ['1', '2', '3', '4'];
var number = parseInt(array.join(''), 10);
alert(number);
```

**Note:** The 10 used in the `parseInt` function above is to specify the `radix` (also known as the base in mathematical numeral systems). 10 signifies the base used in decimal system.